# How to import class name python

Tags: python, import, python-import

Here is my python folder structure (it does not have any python package):

```
 folder/
    script1.py
    script2.py
```

script1 has:

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__():
        print("in init")

    def showReport():
        print("in report only function")
```

script2 has:

```
from . import myclass
```

and when I run python -m folder.script2

I get `/usr/bin/python: cannot import name myclass`

How can I import this class so that I can call functions from this class on script2?

Comment: You can't use relative imports like `from . import blah` unless you make your folder into a package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import a module from a relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

Comment: oh my folder does have  an `__init__.py` which makes it a package I suppose

Comment: Can you fix / double check the spelling of `myclass`? it's spelled here as `myClass` too

Comment: Try `from .script1 import myclass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you do have a package, but you still have to reference the *module* `script1` that contains your class `myclass`, so:

```
from .script1 import myclass
```

P.S. In Python it's customary to use camel case for class names, so `MyClass` not `myclass`

### Example

Working example with a package called `package` and modules `module1` and `module2`, then from outside `package`, I call `python -m package.module2`:

```
➜  ~  tree package

├── __init__.py
├── module1.py
└── module2.py

➜  ~  cat package/module1.py 

class MyClass(object):
    def work(self):
        print 'Working!'

➜  ~  cat package/module2.py 

from .module1 import MyClass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker = MyClass()
    worker.work()

➜  ~  python -m package.module2  

Working!
```

Comment: Thanks. I got ` /usr/bin/python: No module named script1`

Comment: I  am running this script from outside of package python -m folder.script2. FYI. Here I dont have any __init__.py

Comment: ok there was a spelling mistake import worked! but when I try to call a function  using myClass.showReport()`  I get `TypeError: unbound method showReport() must be called with myClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Comment: You didn't instantiate the class, use `x = myClass()` not `x = myClass`, before calling `x.showReport()`, also you need `def showReport(self)`, you forgot `self` in your question. Please copy paste my **working** example then adapt it, you are dealing with many problems simultaneously it will be confusing.

Comment: BTW I notice that though my script runs succesfully I get /usr/bin/python: No module named folder.script2.py at the end.

Comment: No module named `folder.script2.py` the module name is `folder.script2`

Comment: ok yeah by mistake I was running `python -m folder.script2.py`

Answer (score 2):

Try with `from script1 import myclass`